# Dev Console freezes and crashes org when two admins try to login

Tags: developer-console

I just added another system admin user to my developer org and now when we are both logged in and either one of us trys to launch the dev console it does not load and crashes the page; this prompts Microsoft edge to ask us to 'Recover Webpage'. Any ideas what is going on ?

Comment: Could be a browser issue, maybe check in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Its not a browser issue

Comment: That doesn't make sense, never heard of such issue.  I had those issues on edge or internet explorer, even on chrome which I was having a sort of bad connectivity.

Comment: Actually you may be right, I restarted and its working for right now. I'm at work and we're not allowed to install chrome lol

Comment: haha, usually what I do is copy the developer console URL and open in a new tab instead of popup.